# How to make an <a> tag element to trigger multiple functions with javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, function, triggers, call, href

There is a link in my webpage, the link itself triggers a function that I could not modify, but I want to make the link, when clicked, also calls another JavaScript function at the same time or preferably after the first function is done. So one click to call two functions...could it be implemented? Thanks

```
<a title="Next Page" href="javascript:__doPostBack('Booklet1','V4504')">Next</a>
```

is the sample tag I want to modify, how could make it also call "myFunc" at the same time or preferably after _doPostBack is done.

P.S. the function parameter for _doPostBack such as V4504 is dynamically generated by the ASP user control. So I cannot simply treat it as a static function and bind it with another. I think I could only append some function to it? Unless I parse the whole page first and extract the function name with its current parameters...Since every time I click the link, the parameter such as V4504 changes its value....

Thanks!

Comment: Yes. You just need to bind an additional onClick event to the link using js.

Comment: Could you post the html for the A tag?

Comment: using javascript only or jquery?

Comment: Hi jrieiro, preferably just javascript unless it's too complicated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to attach multiple event handlers to a single anchor tag, either with `.onclick` or `.addEventListener('click', function)`

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this MANY ways (I use both `$(this)` and `$('identifier')` as you don't say how the functions are bound) :

```
$(this).click(function(){
   my_function_1();
   my_function2()
});
```

Or

```
$('my element').click(function(){
   my_function_1();
});
$('my element').click(function(){
   my_function_2();
});
```

Or, if the functions reside on another object:

```
$(this).click(function(){
   my_function_1();
   $('#other_element_id').trigger('click'); //there are a bunch of syntaxes for this
});
```

Sans JQuery, you can use:

```
var myObj  = document.getElementById('element name');
myObj.addEventListener('click', function(){
   alert('first!');
});
myObj.addEventListener('click', function(){
   alert('second!');
});
```

Clicking will result in two sequential alert prompts

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks for the quick reply. I'm sorry I did not explain the situation correctly: the function parameter for _doPostBack such as V4504 is dynamically generated by the ASP user control. So I cannot simply treat it as a static function and bind it with another. I think I could only append some function to it? Unless I parse the whole page first and extract the function name with its current parameters...Since every time I click the link, the parameter such as V4504 changes its value....

Comment: OK, post clarification, go with `addEventListener` approach... this will leave existing bound functions alone, but append another action to it.

Comment: Thanks Ben, addEventListener sounds nice, I will try it out first and get back to you.

Comment: I ended up using onclick, but I believe addEventListener would work too. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can attach a handler to an element click event using plain Javascript in such a way:

```
function hello()
{
    alert("Hello!")
}
var element = document.getElementById("YourAElementID");
if (element.addEventListener)
{
    element.addEventListener("click", hello, false);
}
else
{
    element.attachEvent("onclick", hello);
}
```

It supprots all common browsers.

Comment: by the way, you can substitute your __doPostBack function by the new one (like this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/VVPNk/1/)), that call "__doPostBack" and than call your function... but it is a very unsafe way, god knows if this __doPostBack is needed anywhere more